# how to use timer in foreach loop

Tags: c#, timer, foreach

in a company I'm working we want to build an automation tool that should run a script written in text. I'm new to timers, and what I want to do is to make a `foreach` (not a must) that will run line after line in the script and call a parser for later use.
What I want is something like this:

```
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.


        // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
        aTimer.Interval = 2000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        foreach (ScriptCell CELL in ScriptList)
        {
            //fire the method when time is up
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoScriptCommand(CELL.CellText));


        }
```

I know what I wrote doesnt make allot of sense , but I'm a BIT clueless here

PS. I was looking in other topics before posting this Q , but I didnt find nothing that seems to fill the gap

Comment: `+=` doesn't fire an event, it attaches an event handler. Are you asking how to fire the event yourself?

Comment: @Nathan you are of course right! , my intention as as answered by @@Matten .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The introduction of `await` makes acting on each item in a sequence, while waiting for a period of time between each item, very easy:

```
foreach(var cell in ScriptList)
{
    DoScriptCommand(cell.CellText)
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this IN the elapsed event, not a new handler for each line (otherwise they'll be executed in a parallel manner)

```
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler((sender, args) => 
{
    foreach (ScriptCell CELL in ScriptList)
    {
        DoScriptCommand(CELL.CellText);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought it is working , but it threw the error in compiler 
Error 1 Delegate 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler' does not take 0 arguments

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking at running a script or scripts on a regular basis I would search "cron" if you are using a Unix/Linux machine or  "Windows Task Scheduler" if you are using a windows machine. Each of these tools lets you specify a path to a script, the interval they should run, what command line parameters to use etc.

Answer (score -2):

I did little tetris in my application.
I used timer for this code: I hope it will help you.
İf you dont use thread, your program will stuck while timer is running
so i used thread like this:

```
private void ciz()
{
    int beklemeSuresi = 1000;//1000 = 1sec
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        if (g != null)
        {
            g.Clear(Color.AliceBlue);
        }
        solLCiz(100, 100 + i * 20, yon);
        Application.DoEvents();
        Thread.Sleep(beklemeSuresi);
    }
}
```

Of course you must begin thread at beginning of program like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ciz();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```